Illegal mix of collations
I am managing a MariaDB 10.6 Server for a bunch of people. I also dump the databases for backup purposes. Recently, one of the databases started to make problems while dumping:

mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show create table my_view': Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '=' (1267)

Everything in that database was created using the utf8mb4 character set and utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation. I checked the DB, tables, columns and view.
I then found out, that when I open a regular mariadb shell, the collation_connection differs:
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE "collation_connection";
+----------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value              |
+----------------------+--------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+----------------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.002 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "collation_connection";
+----------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value              |
+----------------------+--------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8mb4_general_ci |
+----------------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.003 sec)

My first question: Why does the global scope have a different collation_connection compared to the session scope? I always thought the session scope inherits from the global scope. I was not able to find in the docs, where this gets set.
Here are the relevant parts of my mariadb option file:
[mariadb]
character_set_server=utf8mb4
collation_server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mariadb-dump]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

My second question: How to prevent such issues? Do I have to tell all of my users to use the same collation to prevent issues like that?

Here is an example to reproduce it:
CREATE TABLE employees (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    department VARCHAR(100),
    salary DECIMAL(10, 2),
    created_at TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO employees (name, department, salary, created_at)
VALUES
    ('Alice', 'HR', 50000, NOW()),
    ('Bob', 'Engineering', 70000, NOW()),
    ('Charlie', 'HR', 45000, NOW()),
    ('David', 'Engineering', 80000, NOW()),
    ('Eve', 'Marketing', 60000, NOW());

SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE VIEW hr_employees AS
SELECT id, name, salary
FROM employees
WHERE department = 'HR' AND date_format(created_at, "%Y") IN ('2024');

SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_general_ci;

SHOW CREATE VIEW hr_employees;
ERROR 1267 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='


What was the setting when running CREATE TABLE...?

Connection collation can be set in many places - option files, command line, startup script and so on. When the client starts, the global variables set is cloned to its connection then the settings specified for the client in all possible places alters the variables values. So you must find the place where this setting is re-assigned, or the place where it can be assigned back to correct value.

There is a (long) Question/Answer about this on stackoverflow.com:  Troubleshooting "Illegal mix of collations" error in mysql

@RickJames They were created with the same settings (collation_connection = utf8mb4_general_ci)

@Akina I was not able to find any place where this is specifically set to utf8mb4_general_ci.. I bypassed the startup script by starting it by hand. There are no other option files..

@Luuk This was very helpful to get an understanding of how character sets and collations work. However I'm still not 100% sure what the problem in my case is. The database collation is utf8mb4_unicode_ci, so the department column that is used in my VIEW should also have this collation. As my collation_connection is utf8mb4_general_ci this rule should apply: If one of the sides has a Unicode character set, and another side has a non-Unicode character set, the side with Unicode character set wins, and automatic character set conversion is applied to the non-Unicode side.

Look at the definition of the TABLE that the VIEW is based on.  That is probably where the column's collation comes from.  Look at it using SHOW CREATE TABLE.

Change your VIEW to:
CREATE VIEW hr_employees AS
SELECT id, name, salary
FROM employees
WHERE department = 'HR'  
  AND date_format(created_at, "%Y" COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci) IN ('2024') 
;

OR you could do, (but that changes the query!):
CREATE VIEW hr_employees AS
SELECT id, name, salary
FROM employees
WHERE department = 'HR' AND date_format(created_at, "%Y") = '2024' COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci
;

see: DBFIDDLE
The error is cause by date_format(created_at, "%Y") IN ('2024').
Adding the COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci solves this.
the only thing I could find about it, is this:

DATE_FORMAT() returns a string with a character set and collation given by character_set_connection and collation_connection so that it can return month and weekday names containing non-ASCII characters.

